# How to prevent matplotlib from dropping points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot a fairly dense dataset (up to 60000 values), and usually it works quite nice. However, if the dataset contains a few outliers, these get sometimes dropped:

```
[... 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 172, 962, 270, 93, 39, 24, 19, 18, 12, 28, 17, 18, 11,
 7, 7, 8, 6, 4, 3, 9, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4,
 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1,
 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, ...]
```

would result in a flat graph, not showing the spike up to almost 1000. Obviously this is very undesirable. Plotting works correctly if I switch to points instead of lines, but that's not as precise and harder to parse visually.

My code is really simple:

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ts, my_points) 

png_file_in_memory = cStringIO.StringIO()
backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig).print_figure(png_file_in_memory)
return png_file_in_memory
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: Could you make this into a runnable example so we can see the results and what exactly is going wrong? My guess is that the spike doesn't show up due to resolution limitations (but it's just a guess).

Comment: Hard to say... this works for me: `a = np.random.rand(60000)`
`a[np.random.randint(0,60000, 25)] = 25` `plt.plot(a)`